# Cannot insert new row into view using trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert

I'm currently inserting this data `{"curr": "testcurr","nm": "testnm"}`
to a view.

A trigger function is then run to insert into the original tables instead.

I'm getting an error `cannot insert into column "curr" of view "tblview"` from the trigger function.

Here is the part of my code:

```
IF (tg_op = 'INSERT') THEN
                NEW."dat"= jsonb_build_object("curr",NEW.'curr','symb',NEW."symb");
                NEW."ct"=now();
                INSERT INTO data.tbl
                    (
                    "nm",
                    "dat",
                    "ct",
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                    NEW."nm",
                    NEW."dat"
                    NEW."ct"
                    )returning "id" into NEW.id;
END
```

Here is my view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW data.tblview AS
 SELECT gn.id,
    gn.nm,
    ((gn.dat ->> 'curr'::text))::character varying(64) AS curr,
    ((gn.dat ->> 'symb'::text))::character varying(64) AS symb,
    gn.ct
   FROM data.gn
```

So what is the reason why I can't insert a new row?

Comment: you cant insert into view. view is RO object. basically view is just a select RULE. it only selects - not holds any data

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html

> The view is not physically materialized. Instead, the query is run
>   every time the view is referenced in a query.

So you can't insert into view by the definition

Comment: okay, so what if I actually want to insert into the original table instead? Because I'm getting the same error

Comment: insert into data.tbl fails with same error?.. please quite the exact messange in OP

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a BEFORE INSERT trigger?

I believe you should create your trigger to be "INSTEAD OF INSERT", this way postgres will not attempt to insert into the view, which will fail.